# How to create an Rx Search view that will filter a recycler view with a query

Tags: android, rx-java

I want to implement a Rx Search view that will filter a recycler view with the string and also check the local Realm db and make a retrofit request, then combines all the results without duplicates ?? So, in other words: I would like to on text change event in a search view, to use the input string to make a network request, a db query and combine with results without duplicates

This is my initial code:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
            .filter(charSequence -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence))
            .throttleLast(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .flatMap(charSequence -> userListPresenter.search(charSequence))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
            .subscribe((Action1) response -> userListPresenter.showSearchResult((List<UserModel>) response));
```

The userListPresenter.search(charSequence)) should return an observable of the concatenated response without duplicates, thanks :)

userListPresenter.search(charSequence)):

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
            if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                subscriber.onNext(restApi.search(query));
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }).mergeWith(
                    Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscriber.onNext(realmManager.getWhere(query));
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    })).collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::add)
            .flatMap(Observable::from);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I correctly understood your question. There is good way to combine the emissions of multiple Observables, look at [zip method](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).
So, Your search method would be look like that:

```
public Observable<List<MyItem>> search(CharSequence query) {
    return Observable.zip(
                observeNetwork(query),
                observeRealm(query),
                new Func2<List<MyItem>, List<MyItem>, List<MyItem>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<MyItem> call(List<MyItem> networkResult, List<MyItem> databaseResult) {
                        return merge(networkResult,databaseResult);
                    }
                }
            );
}

private Observable<List<MyItem>> observeRealm(CharSequence searchString) {
    return Observable.create( /* do your realm stuff */);
}

private Observable<List<MyItem>> observeNetwork(CharSequence searchString) {
    return return Observable.create( /* do your network stuff */);
}

private List<MyItem> merge(List<MyItem> networkResult, List<MyItem> databaseResult) {
    List<MyItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(databaseResult);
    for(MyItem newItem : networkResult){
        if(!databaseResult.contains(newItem)){
            result.add(newItem);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```